# How to check if my Cytoscape.js graph is out of view (even partially) after panning and/or zooming?

Tags: javascript, viewport, cytoscape.js

I want to check if my graph is out of view, maybe after panning and/or zooming, so that i can activate the Cytoscape navigator.

Examples:

These are out of view
[image]

[image]

But this is not:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What do you do if the graph is out of view?

Comment: I initialize the cytoscape-navigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function isGraphOutOfView() {
  const width = cy.width();
  const height = cy.height();
  const boundingBox = cy.elements().boundingbox();
  const pan = cy.pan();
  const zoom = cy.zoom();

  return boundingBox.x1 * zoom + pan.x < 0
    || boundingBox.y1 * zoom + pan.y < 0
    || boundingBox.x2 * zoom + pan.x > width
    || boundingBox.y2 * zoom + pan.y > height;
}
```

Edit: with `renderedBoundingBox`:

```
function isGraphOutOfView() {
  const width = cy.width();
  const height = cy.height();
  const rbb = cy.elements().renderedBoundingbox();

  return rbb.x1 < 0 || rbb.y1 < 0 || rbb.x2  > width || rbb.y2  > height;
}
```

Comment: Hi! I was trying to solve it myself, and have got this code working:

`canvasWidth = $(cy.container()).width();
 canvasHeight = $(cy.container()).height();
function isOutOfView(){
    let {x1,x2,y1,y2,w,h} = cy.$().renderedBoundingBox();
    return x1 < 0 || y1 < 0 || x2 > canvasWidth || y2 > canvasHeight;
}`

Are there any differences (performance/correctness) between the two codes?

Comment: Isn't it as same as my code? Multiplying with zoom and adding pan gives you the rendered position.

Comment: "Multiplying with zoom and adding pan gives you the rendered position" - that's something i just learnt from you ;)